# Incorrect syntax near '('. Sql server

Tags: sql-server, script

Tengo un query para ver la desfragmentacion de los indices pero al correrlo en la plataforma de produccion me manda este error

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Al correrlo en otra base, lo corre sin problema alguno.

Dejo el script

```
SELECT dbschemas.[name] AS 'Schema',
dbtables.[name] AS 'Table',
dbindexes.[name] AS 'Index',
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent AS 'Frag',
indexstats.page_count AS 'Page count'
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables ON dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas ON dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

el error dice que esta en la linea 6

```
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near '('.

Pero la verdad no le veo nada distinto

Comment: Deberías echar un vistazo a [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/db-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-db_id-to-specify-the-value-of-a-system-function-parameter) en el que te muestran cómo hacer uso de `DB_ID()` como parámetro de una función de sistema.

Comment: @OscarGarcia le di una revisada ... DB_ID toma el valor asignado del identificador de la db, ya le asigne el id de la db (7) y el nombre pero sigue marcando el error.

Comment: ¿El mismo error en la misma línea? ¿Qué versión de SQL Server usas?

Comment: Asi es, mismo error, misma linea
SQL Server 10.50.1600.1 es la versión que estoy utilizando

Comment: Eso es SQL Server 2008 R2. Muy vieja para usar DB_ID...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es averiguar los parámetros de la función donde está almacenada.

Dado que sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats es una función tipo tabla de la base de datos master. Por ejemplo desde Sql Management Studio, puedes ir a través del árbol del Object Explorer y localizar la misma.

[image: object Explorer]

Verifica que te muestra tantos parámetros y del mismo tipo, como le estás pasando en la query.

Ahora bien, además de que la función este y sea visible y los parámetros encajen en tipo, hace falta satisfacer los requerimientos que tiene la misma.

La base de datos, sobre la que opera la función DB_ID, tiene que tener un nivel de compatibilidad....(aquí la documentación actual ya no ofrece datos, porque corresponde a un Sql Server 2016), pero puede ser un punto importante.

[Ver o cambiar nivel de compatibilidad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

Y luego queda por saber los permisos que dispone el usuario que ejecuta la consulta.

> Necesita los siguientes permisos:
>
> El permiso CONTROL en el objeto especificado en la base de datos.
>
> Permiso VIEW DATABASE STATE para devolver información sobre todos los
> objetos de la base de datos especificada, mediante el uso del carácter
> comodín de objeto @object_id= null.
>
> Permiso VIEW SERVER STATE para devolver información sobre todas las
> bases de datos mediante el carácter comodín de base de datos
> @database_id = null.

La mejor manera de ir cercando el problema, es dividirlo. Si te dice error de sintaxis en esa función, ejecuta la consulta únicamente contra la función, y vete anexando conjuntos según vayas solucionando, el problema.

Cambia en nombre de la base de datos de la sentencia de asignación Set @db_id, por el nombre de la base de datos. Y cubre también la sentencia de asignación con los valores apropiados, del @Object_id

```
DECLARE @db_id SMALLINT;  
DECLARE @object_id INT;  
  
SET @db_id = DB_ID(N'database');  
SET @object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'database.eschema.nombreTabla');  
  
    SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(@db_id, @object_id, NULL, NULL , 'LIMITED');
```